# MySQL Records are being deleted for unknown reasons

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I have a small database with 7 tables inside it and a few options from a PHP website for insert and update options. By unknown reason some of the records inside the database are getting deleted on a random order and I don't have any idea what can cause this. Any idea how to observe this problem or what should be done ? Is there a way to put restriction on the entire database that delete option to be disabled ?

Comment: If you have URLs that have an id to delete in them, google could be crawling them

Comment: Check for triggers also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to create a MySQL user which can't delete rows, or do anything else nasty. Then, the program can be changed to use that MySQL user, instead of whatever is currently being used (look for wherever the MySQL connection is set up, perhaps from a configuration file).

Log into MySQL. Then, create a restricted user using something like:

```
GRANT SELECT on database_name.* to 'read-only-user' IDENTIFIED BY 'some-password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Here is a helpful documentation page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html . If your application needs to be able to do more than just read, adapt the above to something like `GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE`. Consult the link for more information.

As for finding the cause of the problem, it depends a lot on how your application is written (whether it's using an ORM for accessing the database, etc.). You might find that your application errors as soon as you restrict the user as above; that's good, if so, as the error message should show you where to look.

Otherwise, if everything for your database goes through a central place, you might be able to add some logging within the application (or maybe there's some configuration setting already available in your application for that). If SQL statements are scattered throughout, you might like to try searching the code for DELETE or DELETE FROM (case-insensitive). Alternatively, you could set up logging for the queries within MySQL itself, but this is not quite as straightforward, and still wouldn't tell you where in the application the DELETEs are happening (but if other approaches fail, this would at least give you more information about where to look).